# How to use Method projects.agent.import of DialogFlow for importing zip file to agent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dialogflow-es, agent

I want to use dialogflow v2 api to upload a zip file to an agent , but i am not able to understand the documentation properly , can anyone help me by telling the way to use the api for importing a zip file using api in Nodejs .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To import via the API, you must either:

- Send a request to the API endpoint with `agentContent` body property set to the base64-encoded value of the ZIP file (ie, you're "uploading" the file)
- Send a request to the API endpoint with the `agentUri` body property set to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket address (beginning with `gs://`) that points to the location of an agent you wish to import.

The latter is far more reliable, as the import is done internally within GCP, and works in tandem with [`project.agents.export`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent/export) function (whereby you can pass it an `agentUri` to backup the current agent state to). Note that if on the export you omit the `agentUri`, it instead returns a response with `agentContent` set to the base64-encoded representation of the ZIP file.

For example:

```
POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/YOUR-GCP-PROJECT-ID/agent:import

Request (JSON)
{
  "agentUri": "gs://your-storage-bucket-address/path/to/the/import.zip",
}
```

OR

```
POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/YOUR-GCP-PROJECT-ID/agent:import

Request (JSON)
{
  "agentContent": "+ZSUFAqSy0qzszPU7JSUDLUM9AzUOKqBQBQSwcIozeueBoAAAAYAAAAUEs...", // etc
}
```

Please see the [Google `projects.agent.import` reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent/import) for the exact specification on this.